# nth root implementation

Tags: java, math, nth-root

I am working on a way to calculate the n<sup>th</sup> root of a number. However, I am having problems with the n<sup>th</sup> root of negative numbers.

Most people say to use `Math.pow(num, 1 / root)`, but this does not work for negative numbers.

I have tried this:

```
public static double root(double num, double root) {
    if (num < 0) {
        return -Math.pow(Math.abs(num), (1 / root));
    }
    return Math.pow(num, 1.0 / root);
}
```

but, it does not work for all numbers as the root can be a decimal. For example `root(-26, 0.8)` returns `-58.71`, but that is an invalid input. This will also give the wrong answer for even roots. For example `root(-2, 2)` returns `-1.41421`, but -2 does not have a square root.

Comment: roots of negative numbers are complex, java has no built in support for complex numbers

Comment: -2 has two square roots.

Comment: I'm not including imaginary numbers.

Comment: Then you can throw out all even roots of negative numbers.

Comment: Please clarify why it is invalid. (26)^(1/0.8) = 58.17

Comment: @scienwhatever: Because the answer is -41.515-41.515i.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What are you trying to do?  Unless you're planning to fully and properly handle complex numbers you cannot take the nth root of a negative number.

For example, while `(-8)^(1/3)` has a principal branch of `-2`, the only branches of `(-4)^(1/2)` are `2i` and `-2i`.

To handle this properly you need to transform the number into its polar form and then take the required root in that form.

So `-8` is the complex number `8*exp(i*pi)`.  The `1/3` roots of that are `2*exp(i*pi/3)`, `2*exp(i*pi)`, and `2*exp[i*(-pi)/3]`.  Then you can use [de Moivre' formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) to compute the roots in the form `a + bi`.

Answer (score 18):

`(num) ^ (1/root)` is similar to `exp( (1/root) * log(num) )`, so you can do it like:

```
public static double root(double num, double root)
{
    return Math.pow(Math.E, Math.log(num)/root);
}
```

Comment: ` return Math.pow(Math.E, Math.log(num)/root); ` Eng Fouad your method does not provide a correct answer.Proper code should be written like this `Math.pow(Math.exp (1/root),Math.log(num)); `

Comment: @IliyaGino - I think the variable name `root` is not the root itself, but is the inverse of the desired power (so, for example, if `root == 2`, then calling `root(3.0, 2)` should return the square root of 3.

Comment: I tried to use your code, it returns 1.9999999998 instead of 2 for the square root of 4, root(4,2). How to make it return 2. Cheers

Comment: @FeayJaranaManotumruksa You can't expect a floating point function to give an exact answer.  It's just not going to happen.

Comment: This is the correct one

Answer (score 2):

Either use one of the many complex number packages available on the Internet, or convert your number to a rectangular position on the Argand plane, rotate it the appropriate angle as given by the root, then read it out as a (real, imaginary) pair.

Answer (score 2):

I use the method below. Maybe it's not the most accurate, but it works well in my case.

```
public double root(double num, double root) {
    double d = Math.pow(num, 1.0 / root);
    long rounded = Math.round(d);
    return Math.abs(rounded - d) < 0.00000000000001 ? rounded : d;
}
```

Comment: This will not work for `num<0`, which is the whole point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do
        if(num < 0){
            return Math.abs(Math.pow(num, 1 / root))
        }
Then just use ' + "i"' whenever stating the value. Or use the absolute value for equations and later factor in the positive/negative and i when needed. That's what worked for me.

Comment: But this will lead to buggy code, since the function won't indicate whether its returned value is real or purely imaginary.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public double root(double num, double root) {
        double y=1;
        double x;
        while(Math.pow(x, root) != num) {
            if(Math.pow(x, root) > num) {
                x=x-y;
                y=y/10;
            } else {
                x=x+y;
            }
        }
        return x;
    }
```

This should work fine for you, although it isn't compact it uses as little math functions as possible.

Comment: This will computes the root one digit at a time, which will be extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about the exact code, but add an extra if statement to clarify between odd and even roots. something along the lines of

```
public static double root(double num, double root) {
    if (num < 0) {
        if(root%2==1) {
            return -Math.pow(Math.abs(num), (1 / root));
        }
    }
    return Math.pow(num, 1.0 / root);
}
```

Not entirely sure if this will work with your other code, but I hope it can help

Answer (score -2):

System.out.println( Math.pow(10, Math.log10(Number)/root));

Comment: Yes, but we prefer you include some english explaining your answer.  (And you want `num`, not `Number`.)

Comment: @Teepeemm I was providing a logic now it's upto you to make your own theories, bro I am not a teacher who will explain you everything.

Comment: Also, `Math.log10(num)` will fail for `num<0`, which is the whole point of the question.