# exponential 1/3 in Java

Tags: java

Wondering what is the right way to represent `x^(1/3)`? Here is my code and it returns right value `2` for `8^(1/3)`. Wondering if any other better methods?

```
int a = 8;
System.out.println(Math.pow(8, 1/3.0)); // returns 2
```

regards,
Lin

Comment: Better in what sense?

Comment: @azurefrog, more elegant and efficient way.

Comment: @azurefrog, how would you write the same logic, btw?

Comment: What does "elegant" mean? Efficient in what dimension(s)?

Comment: For specifically a cube root, I'd probably use `Math::cbrt(double a)`, but for general exponentiation, `Math::pow(double a, double b)` is what I'd use.

Comment: But then, I'm usually working on engineering problems, so 2.9999 == 3 as far as I care.  If you're working on something algebraic, floating numbers would be bad.

Comment: You might get better answers on http://codereview.stackexchange.com, which is where this question belongs.

Comment: @LewBloch, for elegant I mean more formal. How do you calculate n^(1/m) btw?

Comment: @DavidWallace, thanks but since it is just one line of code so I just ask here. How do you calculate n^(1/m) btw?

Comment: @azurefrog, thanks and it seems you are also using `Math::pow(double a, double b)`, but how it is related to your comments "floating numbers would be bad"? I think return float/double is more general case for `Math.pow`?

Comment: What you started with is about as formal as it gets, and probably fairly efficient because it uses a library method. I doubt that you can improve on it.

Comment: @LewBloch, thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a [`Math.cbrt` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cbrt(double)) for x<sup>1/3</sup>.

```
System.out.println(Math.cbrt(8));
```

See also:

- [Time complexity of the Math.cbrt(a) method in java.math library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28538292/time-complexity-of-the-math-cbrta-method-in-java-math-library)
- [nth root implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325793/nth-root-implementation) (If you want to compute x<sup>1/n</sup>)

Comment: Ah, the cube root (horrible method name)

Comment: Thanks kennytm, if for any root, not necessarily to be cube root, is there a general function (e.g. for n ^ (1/m))?

Comment: @LinMa No there isn't. Use `Math.pow(x, 1/n)` as you have written, or the implementation by the asker of the second linked question if you want to deal with odd roots of negative numbers as well.

Comment: Thanks kennytm for the confirm, mark your reply as answer.